# Can't capture the correct image data on canvas using ctx.getImageData()

Tags: reactjs, canvas

A lot of copy and pasting, mashing, and reworking things, but I was finally able to successfully extract an image of the cropped area of the canvas. Only issue was the canvas image was extremely blurry, as was the resulting cropped area image. After doing some digging, I found a solution - account for the device pixel ratio. This cleared up the canvas and cropped image, but the cropped image is now very zoomed in. I'm guessing this is because of the inclusion of the device pixel ratio calculations. I've tried toying with the cropImage function, but can't "zoom out" the cropped area image. Any idea what I need to change in that function?

```
import {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react'
import {motion} from 'framer-motion'  

const [ canvasDimensions, setCanvasDimensions ] = useState(null)
const [ cropCoords, setCropCoords ] = useState(null)
const canvasRef = useRef()
const containerRef = useRef()
const cropRef = useRef()
const dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

function updateCropCoords() {
    const {x, y, width, height} = cropRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()
    setCropCoords({...x: x, y: y})
}

function cropImage() {
    const { x, y, w, h } = cropCoords
    const { left, top } = containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()
    const relativeXPos = x - left
    const relativeYPos = y - top

    const originalContext = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
    const imageData = originalContext.getImageData(relativeXPos, relativeYPos, w, h);
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.rect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    const croppedDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    console.log(croppedDataUrl)
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (canvasRef.current) {
        const context = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d", { antialias: false });
        context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        context.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

        canvasRef.current.width = canvasDimensions.width * dpr
        canvasRef.current.height = canvasDimensions.height * dpr
        canvasRef.current.style.width = `${canvasDimensions.width}px`
        canvasRef.current.style.height = `${canvasDimensions.height}px`;

        const image = new Image();
        image.src = SomeImage;
        image.onload = () => {
            context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvasDimensions.width * dpr, canvasDimensions.height * dpr);
            context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}, [])

return (
    <>
        <div ref={containerRef} className="container">
            <canvas ref={canvasRef} className="canvas" />
            <motion.span className="cropArea" ref={cropRef} drag onDragEnd={updateCropCoords} />
        </div>
        <button type="button" onClick={cropImage}>Crop</button>
    </>
)
```

Comment: You seem to be close to finding yourself. Take some time and review your code that does scale the canvas so that it's now sharp on High density monitors. Can you see how it works? You get the relation between the displayed size (i.e. the one defined in CSS) and the "natural" one (the number of pixels your canvases are made of)? You have to make yet another such scaling from the cropping coords (that are defined in the CSS world) to the "natural" canvas's coords.

Comment: Also and unrelated, instead of cropping through `getImageData()` + `putImageData()` you'd be better using all the params of `drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)`, this way your main canvas can stay hardware accelerated.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you for putting me on the right track! Adjusted the getImageData function along with the sizing of the newly created canvas to account for the dpr and everythig is working as it should. It's not quite as crispy as the original canvas image, but it'll do.

Comment: @Kaiido Also tried your suggestion of using drawImage instead but was running into problem after problem - it "appeared" like it was painting a cropped image over the original image, I could get the crop position right but the cropped output was either too zoomed in or zoomed out. I'll play around with it more later when I'm a bit more recharged.